Is there an issue if two asyncio tasks, one reads and one writes, uses one single websocket at the same time?
I have the following simplified code:
import asyncio
import websockets

async def read_from_ws(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        print(f"Received message: {message}")

async def write_to_ws(websocket):
    while True:
        message = input("Enter a message to send: ")
        await websocket.send(message)

async def main():
    uri = "ws://localhost:12345"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        # Launch two concurrent tasks: one for reading and one for writing
        await asyncio.gather(
            read_from_ws(websocket),
            write_to_ws(websocket),
        )

asyncio.run(main())

As you can see, there are two asyncio tasks, one only handles reads, and one only handles writes.
Someone mentioned to me "websockets are not thread, or task-safe and it could lead to data corruptions" and that I should use asyncio.Lock() and wrap the read/write.
What would this mean exactly?
I'm using python3.11 .

Thread safety is indeed a critically important issue in multi-threading, but it does not apply at all to asyncio - unless asyncio is deliberately combined with multi-threading. The term "task-safe" makes no sense when doing I/O in asyncio. Using a lock to mutually exclude the reader and the writer could lead to deadlocks quite easily. I'm very skeptical about the quality of the advice you've got.

@VPfB: Indeed. So much I just quoted that in the response bellow, for added emphasis.

you can read and write to one socket at the same time on any implementation that exists today, just don't have 2 readers or 2 writers from 1 socket at the same time

One of the biggest advantages of asyncio based code, compared to threading code is that code simply doesn't jump from the middle of a function to another in the middle of the function - that just ever happen at await expressions (or async for and async with) statements -
Which means the code above should be just ok. I really doubt
the websockets code will be that async unsafe to the point a write could happen in the middle of a read - and even them, the (underlying) socket mechanics should just allow one happen without messing with the other.
However, to be on the safe side, and not depend on other not doing their homework, adding an explicit lock can be a good idea. When a Lock object is "acquired" any other concurrent code trying to "acquire" it will have to wait until its released.  It is a matter of creating an asyncio.Lock() instance, and using these methods.
The problem with locks is that they will wait forever by default - and in this simplified code, it would lock for reading in the async for statement, and prevent the websocket to be written to, and thus, to ever get a response from the other end -
the simple code would simply lead you to an automatically deadlock (you can't read a response if no response comes from the other side, and the other side will never write something since the websocket is locked out, awaiting for some message)
So I will also quote the comment from @VPfB, above, here, as it is very proper:

Thread safety is indeed a critically important issue in
multi-threading, but it does not apply at all to asyncio - unless
asyncio is deliberately combined with multi-threading. The term
"task-safe" makes no sense when doing I/O in asyncio. Using a lock to
mutually exclude the reader and the writer could lead to deadlocks
quite easily. I'm very skeptical about the quality of the advice
you've got.

so we need to just hold the lock for long enough to see if there is a message ready, otherwise release it. This requires something a bit more elaborated than just holding the lock whenever the async for ... in websocket line is executed. (Which itself requires a logic a bit more elaborated than encapsulating the whole async for block inside a with lock: block)
Just to say it again, in other words: asyncio has been created just to avoid this level of worry when uisng concurrency - I really doubt websocket code would get in trouble if used the way you had - as it has to explicitly pause in places where a state change could mess things up - and not check for any mess after the pause. It would almost be harder to write asycio-unsafe code than asyncio-safe code, and I doubt very much the authors of a production quality package such as websockets would do so.
Anyway, this is how a lock can be used in this code:
import asyncio
import websockets

async def block_free_iterator(iterator, lock):
    while True:
        # allow other tasks to run before we try to fetch an item
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        with lock:
            try:
                # with the lock activated, check if there is an item immediatelly 
                # ready . otherwise, this will timeout.
                
                # without the timeout wrapping we would wait for a message forever,
                # but with the websocket.send method locked out,
                # so one would likely never get back here.
                next_item = asyncio.wait_for(anext(iterator), timeout=0)
            except TimeoutError:
                # no ready next_item
                pass
        yield result
        
    

async def read_from_ws(websocket, lock):
    async for message in block_free_iterator(websocket, lock):
                await lock.release()

async def write_to_ws(websocket, lock):
    while True:
        message = input("Enter a message to send: ")
        # here we can use the simpler form of acquiring/releasing the lock
        # which does away with the "try/finally" needs:
        async with lock:
            await websocket.send(message)

async def main():
    
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    uri = "ws://localhost:12345"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        # Launch two concurrent tasks: one for reading and one for writing
        await asyncio.gather(
            read_from_ws(websocket, lock),
            write_to_ws(websocket, lock),
        )

asyncio.run(main())


